# Issue Using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am writing a program that needs to read data from an input text file, and save a variables upon going through the date. I am using Htmlunit, and am running into the error:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking open
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:616)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:985)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:210)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:230)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:804)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:738)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:869)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:874)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.doClickFireClickEvent(HtmlElement.java:1311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1253)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1205)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1160)
    at Docketscraper.scrapeWebsite(Docketscraper.java:58)
    at Docketscraper.starter(Docketscraper.java:40)
```

My code to do this is:

```
  private static String startingMonth;
  private static String startingDay;
  private static String startingYear;
  private static String endingMonth;
  private static String endingDay;
  private static String endingYear;

  public static void starter() throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("inputfile.txt").useDelimiter("\\s*|/");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
      startingMonth = sc.next();
      startingDay = sc.next();
      startingYear = sc.next();
      // skip "to"
      sc.next();
        endingMonth = sc.next();
      endingDay = sc.next();
      endingYear = sc.next();
      scrapeWebsite();
    }
  }
```

where scrapeWebsite runs the htmlunit method. The scrapeWebsite method is as follows which calls a method to parse through the data:

```
public static void scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {


    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlElement button = form.getElementById("SheetContentPlaceHolder_C_searchresults_lbPrint");
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    try {
      synchronized (page2) {
        page2.wait(10000);
      }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
      System.out.println("error");
    }
    originalHtml = page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    obtainInformation();  
    originalHtml = "";
  }
```

The input variables create the url to search based upon the code:

```
private static String url = "http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dCity%26searchString%3d%26foreclosureType%3d%26dateFrom%3d" + startingMonth + "%2f" + startingDay + "%2f" + startingYear + "+12%3a00%3a00+AM%26dateTo%3d" + endingMonth + "%2f" + endingDay + "%2f" + endingYear + "+11%3a59%3a59+PM";
```

which is the url specific to the website. I believe it is a an issue with the scanner method because when I manually input numbers for the 6 variables and run "scrapeWebsite", the correct output occurs. I can not get even one input set of dates to run which are in the format:

```
1/1/2013 to 1/7/2013
```

I am not sure what is the problem with the "starter" method

Comment: Could you post the full exception?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi the full error has been updated

Comment: It would be nice to see the `scrapeWebsite` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while using HtmlUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249317/error-while-using-htmlunit)

Comment: Yes, Connor, I deleted my comment.  I misunderstood your problem when I first read it - I thought you were translating the URL into the file, not the other way around.  Sorry.

Comment: @DavidWallace The scrapeWebsite method has been added

Comment: So, I don't understand.  `scrapeWebsite` appears not to use `startingDay`, `startingMonth` and the others at all.  How were you expecting those values to be picked up?

Comment: @DavidWallace scrape website uses url to create the webpage, which uses the variables implemented in the string.

Comment: I still don't see any code that sets `url` based on `startingDay` and the others.  Which class has the code that does that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the `Scanner` itself. It is only a matter of getting not well-formed javascript in the request. HtmlUnit tries to parse it and it fails throwing an exception.

I've added to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646612/crypto-not-defined-for-htmlunit-test/19646986#19646986) some ideas on this issue.

Apart from that you could always suppress the exception with [setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setThrowExceptionOnScriptError%28boolean%29).

This will get you through the exception but will not correct any issue in the javascript code. If the javascript function that is giving you trouble happens to be a critical part in your data extraction process then you will have no other choice than forgetting about Javascript handled by HtmlUnit and start coding yourself the AJAX requests. On the other hand, if the Javascript function doesn't have anything to do with the actual processing that you need then this is most likely to work.

This issue is very common when it comes to webscraping in HtmlUnit.

Answer (score 0):

The first problen i noticed was the line

```
Scannersc = new Scanner("inputfile.txt").useDelimiter("\\s*|/");
```

The scanner is now reading the text "inputfile.txt".so try replace it by new File("inputfile.txt"); but if you use this class in another class, it is better to have the whole directory eg"\C:\programdata\Connors file\inputfile.txt" this is an example so the easiest thing to get the directory is go to the folder it is in, right click on the file properties and copy the directory and add\inputfile.txt.
Please let me know if this helps.

Ps.
In case of emergancy
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("inputfile.txt")).useDelimiter("delimiter");